# How install a module in spyder

Tags: python, installation, module, spyder, setuptools

I  installed a module by cmd and setup.py. my module is installed on site packege and worked good in python shell. But in spyder , my module is not working and says me no module.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select your python interpreter in Tool > Preferences > Python Interpreter > Use the following python Interpreter > (path to python.exe)

Make sure to restart your console or spyder.